# React js in Aurelia js, call aurelia function

Tags: reactjs, aurelia

Am very new to react js and aurelia js, my requirement is use react for view and aurelia for model/routing and all. I refered this [doc](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/03/how-to-use-react-js-in-aurelia/) for installation, it works well.[image] Done like this,here my view is in react js, while clicking the details in the table(doted icons),needs to call a function which should be in aurelia.
I followed the above mentioned doc for coding, instead of list in the  **my-react-element.jsx** i changed into table style like in the pic.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, i got it. just understand passing value to components (custome-component in aurelia, component in react). In both, aurelia and react it works nearly same(like call-back function).
Code : 
**react-example.js** Just declare a function, which you want to execute.

```
myfun(){
  alert('Hi, am in aurelia..');
```

}

**react-example.html** use **bind** to set the declared function to custome-component.

```
 <react-element myfun.bind = "myfun"></react-element>
```

**react-example.js**

```
@bindable('myfun')
<MyReactElement data={this.data} myfun={this.myfun}/>,
```

**my-react-element.jsx**

```
 <p onClick = {this.try.bind(this)} >click </p>

 try() {
   this.props.myfun(); }
```

Note : Basic knowledge of react and aurelia required and compare the [doc](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/03/how-to-use-react-js-in-aurelia/)  to fix.